# Programmatically downloading Oracle Business Intelligence report using java

Tags: java, oracle, download, business-intelligence, obiee

I need to download an OBI report as csv using java. When I enter

```
http://<my_host>:<my_port>/analytics/saw.dll?Go&Action=Download&path=<my_path>&Format=csv
```

in a browser, download pop-up appears and I can download the file.

However, when i try to download the report using java, it downloads an html content saying
"Your browser is not supported by Oracle BI Presentation Services."

Here is piece of code I use:

```
URL url = new URL("http://<my_host>:<my_port>/analytics/saw.dll?Go&Action=Download&path=<my_path>&Format=csv");
URLConnection urlc = url.openConnection();
urlc.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0");
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("file.csv"), 1024);
bis = new BufferedInputStream(urlc.getInputStream());
byte[] data = new byte[1024];
while ((x = bis.read(data, 0, 1024)) >= 0) {
    bos.write(data, 0, x);
}
```

So, how can I download the report?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a complete UA string; the javascript that parses UA is sensitive to it.

As you [discovered elsewhere](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2269263), you hit further problems, with a login page with a javascript redirect to the actual page.